# If you leave an item in the Guide's Crafting Info box and exit, is that item lost?

Tags: terraria

If you leave an item in the Guide's Crafting Info box and exit, is that item lost?

6 Chains have disappeared due to this, and I'm not sure what else I've lost...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you dismiss the dialogue box, the item goes back into your inventory.

Comment: What happens if your inventory is full?